# How to position a button in JavaFX

Tags: button, javafx, layout, netbeans, java-8

I am using NetBeans IDE 8.2 for JavaFX. I already know that in order to change the position of a button I need to use setLayoutX/Y. I have tried this, and there is no effect on the buttons. Here is my code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javafxapplication2;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author coolDawg1234
 */
public class JavaFXApplication2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        String x = "1";
        String y = "0";

        Button btn1 = new Button(x);
        btn1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.print(x);
            }
        });

        Button btn2 = new Button(y);
        btn2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.print(y);
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        root.getChildren().add(btn1);
        btn1.setLayoutX(250);
        btn1.setLayoutY(220);
        root.getChildren().add(btn2);
        btn1.setLayoutX(200);
        btn1.setLayoutY(200);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 1000);

        primaryStage.setTitle("WHAT\'s GOOD MY MANS");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Netbeans gives me 0 errors for this, and everything other than the position of the buttons looks fine to me.

Please help me find my problem.

Comment: thank you for the help, i change the import    `javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;` to 'import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;' and switched out all other instances of `StackPane` to `Pane`

Comment: did it solve your problem? I changed to **Pane** too but nothing happend and still my button appears in the center of **Pane**.

Comment: i know its been a while but if i can remember correctly it did work

Answer (score 5):

The container for your buttons is a `StackPane`. `StackPane` is an implementation of `Pane` such that it will, by default, layout its children at the center of itself. Therefore, whenever the scene needs to perform a layout, `StackPane` will set the `layoutX` and `layoutY` values (therefore overwriting whatever you had set) in its `layoutChildren()` method based on its own layout strategy. This behavior happens for most, if not all, subclasses of `Pane`.

If you need to manually position your child nodes, you need to use the generic [`Pane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) container. You can either choose to subclass it and provide your own layout strategy/logic, or simply set `layoutX` and `layoutY` values on the child nodes directly.

If you need the layout strategy provided by `StackPane`, but you would want it to be positioned slightly different from the default position, then you may be looking for [`translateXProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#translateXProperty) and [`translateYProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#translateYProperty).

Comment: I did the same and used **Pane** instead of **StackPane** and still could not position the items inside a container like **Pane**!!

Answer (score 0):

```
30    root.getChildren().add(btn1);
31    btn1.setLayoutX(250);
32    btn1.setLayoutY(220);
33    root.getChildren().add(btn2);
34    btn1.setLayoutX(200);
35    btn1.setLayoutY(200);
```

Just take the right variable (consistent) btn1 gets two coordinates for the same direktion (250 for X in row 31, and 200 for X in row 34), so that button which has no directly set coordinates, has in this layout the coordinates (0,0).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31388221)